# base.html template only displays 1 block of code instead of multiple

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm creating my base.html file and for some reason only one block is displaying in my base.html file at a time. I am trying to include a nav bar, a footer, and some content in base.html but it will only display one block at a time.

I have a feeling it has something to do with my view class because I am only including one file at a time, however I'm fairly new to starting a Django project and I don't know the common procedure to set up a base.html file.

base.html:

```
{% block nav_bar %}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}No Content to Show!!{% endblock %}
{% block footer %}No Footer Available!!{% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
```

Hoping to have all blocks show up on the page at once!

EDIT: home.html is my homepage content page.

Comment: please share your home.html code

Comment: Also explain exactly what you see and how it differs from what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are extending the 'home.html' from 'base.html'. Please check if you have the right structure as mentioned below and I recommend you to use spaces between the '}' or '{' and what will come after them.

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body >

{% block nav_bar %}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
{% block footer %}{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

home.html :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block nav_bar %}  {% endblock %}
{% block content %}  No Content to Show!!   {% endblock %}
{% block footer %}   No Footer Available!!   {% endblock %}
```